# unexpected behaviour while using redirection manipulation

Tags: bash

The below command is used to copy the input file descriptor as per the GNU manuals:

```
exec 6<&0
```

But when I change the redirection operator like so, the command still works, even though file descriptor '0' points to stdin:

```
exec 6>&0
```

Can anyone explain the reason behind that?

Comment: This question is a general bash programming question not related to Ubuntu. Maybe you should ask it on unix.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @AdrienBeau this question (and any about bash) is perfectly on topic here.

Comment: @Zanna can you explain the reason why file descriptor manipulation is behaving like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash does exactly the same thing for `<&` and `>&`, namely it uses the `dup()` system call to make a copy of a file descriptor.

Any errors due to an attempt to write to a file open for reading and so on will happen when the file descriptor is used for reading or writing contrary to the way it was opened.

Initially, an interactive Bash has  `/dev/tty` opened for read-write as file descriptors 0, 1, and 2.

See [What does exec 3<&1 do](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120532/what-does-exec-31-do) on Unix & Linux SE, where user cuonglm took the trouble to document this behavior using `strace`.